# Clang 13 -O2 produces weird output while gcc does not

Tags: c, gcc, clang, undefined-behavior

Can someone explain to me why the following code gets optimized strangely with clang 13 with the -O2 flag? Using lower optimizations settings with clang and with all optimization settings of gcc I get the expected printed output of "John: 5", however, with clang -O2 or greater optimization flags I get an output of ": 5." Does my code have undefined behavior that I am not aware of? Strangely enough, if I compile the code with -fsanitize=undefined, the code will work as expected. How should I even go about trying to diagnose an issue like this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef size_t usize;

typedef struct String {
    char *s;
    usize len;
} String;

String string_new(void) {
    String string;
    char *temp = malloc(1);
    if (temp == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to allocate memory in \"string_new()\".\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    string.s = temp;
    string.s[0] = 0;
    string.len = 1;
    return string;
}

String string_from(char *s) {
    String string = string_new();
    string.s = s;
    string.len = strlen(s);
    return string;
}

void string_push_char(String *self, char c) {
    self->len = self->len + 1;
    char *temp = realloc(self->s, self->len);
    if (temp == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to allocate memory in \"string_push_char()\".\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    self->s[self->len - 2] = c;
    self->s[self->len - 1] = 0;
}

void string_free(String *self) {
    free(self->s);
}

int main(void) {
    String name = string_new();
    string_push_char(&name, 'J');
    string_push_char(&name, 'o');
    string_push_char(&name, 'h');
    string_push_char(&name, 'n');

    printf("%s: %lu\n", name.s, name.len);

    string_free(&name);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `string_from` looks strange. Why are you assigning the input pointer instead of allocating + `strcpy()`? This also contributes to a memory leak: The original `string.s` is lost and never freed.

Comment: If two compilers generate code that behaves differently, then that's usually a sign that you have some *undefined behavior* in your code.

Comment: In your `string_push_char` you never assign `temp` back to the `self->s`. But `realloc` is not guaranteeing the memory will be at the same place as before. Regarding *"How should I even go about trying to diagnose an issue like this"* - Sometimes just carefully reading the code helps

Comment: Also, `realloc` does not necessarily return the same pointer - data may be moved as needed. You should assign the result from `realloc` back to `self->s`.

Comment: [Let me compile this for you](https://godbolt.org/z/TT1MPsaaY).

Comment: As a few problems: `strlen` doesn't count the string null-terminator; Your `string_new` allocate a single byte which is never used (in fact `string_from` ignores it leading to a memory leak); Because `string_from` doesn't allocate memory for the string data, `string_free` after `string_from` will attempt to free data that might not be freeable; You sometime include the terminator in the length (`string_new` and `string_push_char`) but not in `string_from`. These are only from a very quick look at the code. There are probably other problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `string_push_char` calls `realloc` but then continues to use the old pointer. This will *usually* go well if reallocation happens in place, but of course it's undefined behavior if the memory block gets moved.

However, Clang has a ([controversial](https://lwn.net/Articles/863098/)) optimization where it assumes that the pointer passed to `realloc` *always* becomes invalid, because you're supposed to use the returned pointer instead.

The solution is to assign `temp` back to `self->s` after the null check.

As a side note, your `string_from` is so completely broken that you should remove it and rethink it from scratch.

Comment: @Lundin Good point, done.

Comment: I would rethink the idea of returning the struct instead of pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it a bit different way.

```
typedef size_t usize;

typedef struct String 
{
    usize len;
    char str[];
} String;


String *string_from(char *s) 
{
    usize size = strlen(s);
    String *string = malloc(sizeof(*string) + size + 1);
    if(string)
    {
        string -> len = size + 1; //including null character
        strcpy(string -> str, s);
    }
    return string;
}

String *string_push_char(String *self, char c) {
    usize len = self ? self->len : 1;

    self = realloc(self, len + 1);
    if(self)
    {
        self -> len = len + 1;
        self -> str[self -> len - 2] = c; 
        self -> str[self -> len - 1] = 0; 
    }
    return self;
}

void string_free(String *self) {
    free(self);
}

int main(void) {
    String *str = NULL;
    /* add some allocation checks same as with realloc function (temp pointer etc) */
    str = string_push_char(str, 'J');
    str = string_push_char(str, 'o');
    str = string_push_char(str, 'h');
    str = string_push_char(str, 'n');

    printf("%s: %zu\n", str -> str, str -> len);

    string_free(str);

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/4ardvGcxa

In your code you have plenty issues:

```
String string_from(char *s) {
    String string = string_new();
    string.s = s;
    string.len = strlen(s);
    return string;
}
```

This function will instantly create a memory leak and will assign the (very likely) not reallocable (and possible not modifiable ) memory block to the struct which later you may try to realloc.

Comment: and `string_from` also stores the wrong length.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by @Sebastian Redl, I can add that the code has undefined behavior as per C17 7.22.3.5:

> The realloc function deallocates the old object pointed to by ptr and returns a pointer to a new object that has the size specified by size.

This is one of the things that were poorly specified in C90 and silently clarified in C99. From the C99 rationale V5.10 7.20.3.4:

> *A new feature of C99*: the `realloc` function was changed to make it clear that the pointed-to object is deallocated, a new object is allocated, and the content of the new object is the same as that of the old object up to the lesser of the two sizes. C89 attempted to specify that the new object was the same object as the old object but might have a different address. This conflicts with other parts of the Standard that assume that the address of an object is constant during its lifetime. Also, implementations that support an actual allocation when the size is zero do not necessarily return a null pointer for this case. C89 appeared to require a null return value, and the Committee felt that this was too restrictive.

Notably `clang -O3 -std=c90 -pedantic-errors` still crashes, so this code never worked in clang with any C version.